# Grails spring-security-shiro : working with Apache Shiro subject in gsp - migrating from shiro to spring-security-shiro

Tags: grails, spring-security, shiro

I am upgrading an existing application from Grails 2.4.4 to Grails 3.2.8. I am attempting to migrate from the grails `shiro` plugin to the grails `spring-security-shiro` plugin. I would like to perform the normal login check within a layout template gsp in addition to accessing the logged in user.

Here is what I had before in my layout gsp

**main.gsp**

```
<g:if test="${shiro.principal()}">
    Welcome back 
    <g:link controller="account" action="profile">
        <shiro:principal/>
    </g:link>|
    <g:link controller="auth" action="signOut" class="navbar-brand">Logout</g:link>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <g:link controller="auth" action="login" class="navbar-brand">Login</g:link>
</g:else>
```

Comment: Hi mcroteau. I am migrating from grails 2.2.5 to grails 3.2.9. I was using grails-shiro plugin as well. This plugin is no longer active. Have you been able to migrate to spring-security-shiro?

Comment: Yes, but not without a little work. I also had to make some sacrifices for the first pass. I had to mostly use spring security api, I might end up just having to move completely to spring security. Where are you hung up at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using spring security core's api to perform what I needed. I also needed to create custom login screens which is somewhat expected. You might just make the jump to spring security with custom permissions logic. See below.

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html#securityTagLib

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>
    Welcome back 
    <g:link controller="account" action="profile">
        <sec:username/>
    </g:link>|
    <g:link controller="logout">Logout</g:link>
</sec:ifLoggedIn>
<sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
    <g:link controller="auth" action="your_custom_login">Login</g:link>
</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
```

**Permissions Logic**

I switched from strictly string based permissions to Permission object as recommended

**Account.groovy**

```
static hasMany = [ permissions: Permission ]
```

**Permission**

```
class Permission {

   Account account
   String permission

   static constraints = {
   }
}
```

**How to use:**

```
def permission = accountInstance.permissions.find { 
    it.permission == "account:customer_profile:${accountInstance.id}" 
}
if (!permission){
    flash.message = "You do not have permission to access this..."
    redirect(controller:'controller', action:'index')
    return
}
```